# DRY options menus on Android

Tags: android, android-menu

I'm learning about creating Options Menus for Android apps.

In the [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) it has the following tip for staying DRY with menus:

> Tip: If your application contains
>   multiple activities and some of them
>   provide the same Options Menu,
>   consider creating an activity that
>   implements nothing except the
>   onCreateOptionsMenu() and
>   onOptionsItemSelected() methods. Then
>   extend this class for each activity
>   that should share the same Options
>   Menu. This way, you have to manage
>   only one set of code for handling menu
>   actions and each descendant class
>   inherits the menu behaviors.

This appears problematic. If the `Activity`s that need to share the same options inherit from different classes, what should my `OptionsMenuActivity` inherit from? I read that Java does not support multiple inheritance, so how do you get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your activity that has the code for options menu should extend the Activity class.

```
public class YourRootActivity extends Activity {

// Any other stuff that you want for all activities

 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
 // your main options menu
 }
}
```

Now for the classes that need this menu, make them extend the activity that we created above.

```
class Activity1 extends YourRootActivity {
}
```

In case you want slight modifications in your options menu in the subclasses, you can overwrite the onCreateOptionsMenu method in those classes.

Comment: I understand that approach. But what do I do if Activity1 extends Activity and Activity2 extends some other class?

Comment: Activity2 cannot extend another class. If you define a subclass of Activity, then you must extend Activity or a subclass of Activity. Achie's answer is good

Comment: That is a drawback of Java which can be worked around in most cases by carefully implementing classes and using interfaces to implement such cases. But in our case since we do not want to write all the Android's Activity class, its a tradeoff that we have to make. In the above case there will be instances where we may have to extend TabActivity or MapsActivity. In those and any such other similar cases we will have to implement the options menu code again in the respective activities.

Comment: This seems like a flaw in Android's architecture: I have to repeat myself if I want the same options to apply to activities that extend different classes.

Comment: That is not a flaw in Android's Architecture. May I know why each Activity class of yours extend a different class? Try implementing interfaces and if possible cleanup your code to remove such cases unless absolutely necessary

Comment: Couldn't I have an Activity that sends text to a TextView and another that sends an Array to a ListView (so the Activity extends ListActivity). In this case, it appears I would have to repeat the Menu inflator in each Activity. (btw, I am new to Android)

Comment: Thats absolutely possible and it is possible to just have both those classes extend the custom YourRootActivity as explained above. In case of ListActivity instead of extending ListActivity it can extend just the normal Activity and get the listview from code and set listAdapter on that list. You may want to start a separate thread for that if you need more explanation.

Comment: I'll learn more about Adapters. Thanks for all the explanation so far.